# How to set a parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, isset

In index.php page, I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="parent" value="<?php echo GROUP_ROOT_ID; ?>">
```

`GROUP_ROOT_ID` is a macro, equaling to -1.

If in xyz.php file, we check if the parameter parent has been set or not using the below code:

```
if (isset($_GET['parent'])) {
  //do something
}
```

Why I cannot see parent has been set in xyz.php file? How can I make it be set?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to change `$_GET('parent')` to `$_GET['parent']`
second thing, to set the `$_GET['parent']`, the url of the page should be like this

```
http://example.com/index.php?parent=123
http://example.com/xyz.php?parent=123
```

to use a global variable accessible from different pages, you can do it with $_SESSION

```
// in index.php

session_start();
$_SESSION['parent'] = "value";

// in xyz.php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['parent']))
{ /* ... code ... */ }
```

Comment: Do we have a way not to specify the parent parameter in the url, but still we can check if parent is set or not in xyz.php file? Like in C, parent is like a global variable, if it has been set in index.php file, then in xyz.php, it knows parent has already been set.

Comment: Thanks @Khalid! Your suggestion is really helpful! If I can only use <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="-1"> to set parent, can I still access the parent variable in xyz.php if _SESSION is used?

Comment: @damingzi of course. `$_SESSION` variables are used to store some data that you need to use in different pages. don't forget to start the session using the `session_start();` function.